# Suggestions for nested proofs

Tags: macros, formatting, symbols, environments, theorems

I would like to write down my lecture notes. The proofs of the theorems in this lecture are usually really big. It usually looks like this:

> > **Theorem 1:** Here comes the statement of the Theorem
>
> **Proof.**
>
> 1. Without loss of generality let us assume...
> 2. Claim 1: Statement.
>
> *Proof:* Blah blah \endOfInnerProofSymbol
>
> 3. Claim 2: Statement.
>
> *Proof.* Blah blah \endOfInnerProofSymbol
>
> \endOfProofSymbol

So my question is now, how can I make such nested proofs with another QED-symbol than the parent proof (maybe a filled square)?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! I'm quite sure this has already been discussed.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can simply define a new environment `subproof` that mimics the behavior of `proof` but uses a filled square instead of the default one.

```
\newenvironment{subproof}[1][\proofname]{%
  \renewcommand{\qedsymbol}{$\blacksquare$}%
  \begin{proof}[#1]%
}{%
  \end{proof}%
}
```

You can even give it the optional argument as in

```
\begin{subproof}[Subproof]
```

so to print "Subproof" instead of "Proof".

MWE (note the `\item` after the outer `proof` to let `enumerate` start on a new line)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm,amssymb}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

\newenvironment{subproof}[1][\proofname]{%
  \renewcommand{\qedsymbol}{$\blacksquare$}%
  \begin{proof}[#1]%
}{%
  \end{proof}%
}

\begin{document}
\begin{theorem}
  Here comes the statement of the Theorem
\end{theorem}
\begin{proof}
  \item
  \begin{enumerate}
    \item Without loss of generality let us assume...
    \item Claim 1: Statement.%
    \begin{subproof}[Subproof]
      Blah blah
    \end{subproof}
    \item Claim 2: Statement.%
    \begin{subproof}
      Blah blah
    \end{subproof}
  \end{enumerate} 
\end{proof}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Wow, this is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you very much for this detailed answer!

Comment: I would use `\renewcommand{\qedsymbol}{\ensuremath{\blacksquare}}` in case `\qedsymbol` is used in math mode. This will not happen in the definition of proof environments (that I know of), but just to be sure.